# mp4 Video file that plays sound before video

Tags: android, video, mp4, video-encoding

I am creating a video using an Android app and after [this mp4 Video File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6M08xEphJRCVldGSkw4RkRUcDQ/view?usp=sharing) is created it does not play back properly. The audio will play over a still frame from the video and then once the timer reaches the end then the video will play several moving frames.
This issue is only occurring when I create the video on a Samsung Galaxy S7 and not on any other phones.

I am not experienced in video file encoding so I do not even know where to start with debugging what is wrong with the file. If someone could explain what causes something like this That would be amazing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first video sample decode time in your file is 1506981408/90000 - which is giant - about 4.5 hours into the stream.

So the entry is obviously bogus.

Hard to say where is bogus decode time is coming from - may uninitialized memory of some sort.

See 'stts' box offset 1052223 - first array entry.

I corrected your video and put a copy here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1K1m-YmE28DMXdFemZKbXg0WFk

Comment: Thanks man. I was able to find another thread on this. Apparently Samsung has incorrectly implemented the Camera2 api and that causes the giant decode time. I was able to find a way to correct it.